# Why does this apostrophe in my code show up as a <##> in git/bash?

Tags: windows, git, bash

I have code that looks like this:

```
specifies the maximum points’ interval during
```

(its inside of a comment). When I go to git diff in the bash shell provided by Git for Windows, I get this:

```
 specifies the maximum points<92> interval during
```

I assume this is an easy question for somebody, and I'm also hoping my text files aren't being encoded in a wonky manner or something.

Comment: Are you sure that code belongs to git? I mean git is written in C. The code you pasted in your question neither belongs to git nor bash. I don't really follow your question. Please provide more information about the code.

Comment: It's not an ASCII single quote (0x27, see http://www.asciitable.com/) but rather a Windows CP-1252 right single quote (0x92, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).  And, as @LethalProgrammer noted, this is not really a Git thing.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer I never said this "belonged" to git. It shows up as a result of a 'git diff'.

Comment: @torek I figured it was an encoding I wasn't familiar with. Thanks.

Comment: I mean you tagged this as GIT that's why I asked you.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, I hope this helps:

> Git is to some extent character encoding agnostic.
>
> The contents of the blob objects are uninterpreted sequences of bytes. There is no encoding translation at the core level.
>
> Path names are encoded in UTF-8 normalization form C. This applies to tree objects, the index file, ref names, as well as path names in command line arguments, environment variables and config files (.git/config (see git-config[1]), gitignore[5], gitattributes[5] and gitmodules[5]).
>
> Note that Git at the core level treats path names simply as sequences of non-NUL bytes, there are no path name encoding conversions (except on Mac and Windows). Therefore, using non-ASCII path names will mostly work even on platforms and file systems that use legacy extended ASCII encodings. However, repositories created on such systems will not work properly on UTF-8-based systems (e.g. Linux, Mac, Windows) and vice versa. Additionally, many Git-based tools simply assume path names to be UTF-8 and will fail to display other encodings correctly.
>
> Commit log messages are typically encoded in UTF-8, but other extended ASCII encodings are also supported. This includes ISO-8859-x, CP125x and many others, but not UTF-16/32, EBCDIC and CJK multi-byte encodings (GBK, Shift-JIS, Big5, EUC-x, CP9xx etc.).
>
> Although we encourage that the commit log messages are encoded in UTF-8, both the core and Git Porcelain are designed not to force UTF-8 on projects. If all participants of a particular project find it more convenient to use legacy encodings, Git does not forbid it. However, there are a few things to keep in mind.
>
> git commit and git commit-tree issues a warning if the commit log message given to it does not look like a valid UTF-8 string, unless you explicitly say your project uses a legacy encoding. The way to say this is to have i18n.commitencoding in .git/config file, like this:
>
> [i18n]
>         commitencoding = ISO-8859-1
>
> Commit objects created with the above setting record the value of i18n.commitencoding in its encoding header. This is to help other people who look at them later. Lack of this header implies that the commit log message is encoded in UTF-8.
>
> git log, git show, git blame and friends look at the encoding header of a commit object, and try to re-code the log message into UTF-8 unless otherwise specified. You can specify the desired output encoding with i18n.logoutputencoding in .git/config file, like this:
>
> [i18n]
>         logoutputencoding = ISO-8859-1
>
> If you do not have this configuration variable, the value of i18n.commitencoding is used instead.
>
> Note that we deliberately chose not to re-code the commit log message when a commit is made to force UTF-8 at the commit object level, because re-coding to UTF-8 is not necessarily a reversible operation.